# Spring MVC PageNotFound for data:image/png

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm getting numerous PageNotFound warnings from Spring MVC. The error is the following (note I trimmed down the image to save space):

```
WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/data:image/png/eHBhY2tldCBiZWdpbj0i77u/IiBpZD0iVzVNME1wQ2VoaUh6c .... okEIyXqRlEUkcvlEAgEkEqlONj4z3v/sFDo2+l0Ip/P87f/rtG+XCh0wYbldxbKmwADAE620LYBukjLAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvcDispatcher'
```

The image is embedded into the CSS files so there should be no requests going to the server. I can't seem to figure out how this error is even happening.

I'm using GWT in the front end.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slash before `data`, so its interpreted as a regular URL.

Also the `;base64`extension is missing. I'm not sure if the browser can handle the data then.

Comment: You're right, very strange, the images are all being displayed correctly though and they are automagically being generated by GWT.